# If statement condition not running

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I am checking the for the user_id (it is held in a session) - this is working. Then I am running a `SELECT` query for that user for the database table `click_count`. I am checking to see if that user has any records within it, ie: `$page_count`. If not, I want my `INSERT` statement to run to add that user to the database table along with other data.

The part I do not understand is it seems that my `UPDATE` query is always running. For example no matter which user I login with my query only updates the only user in the database table. IE: Bob is the only user in the click_count table, if I log in with Pete, Bob's record is being updated.

I have tested the value for `$page_count` and it equals 0, so my `INSERT` should be running. I have also tried `if ($page_count === 0) {`

Does anyone see anything I am missing?

```
$curPage = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$clicks = 0;
$setup = 0;
$page_total_count = 0;
var_dump($user_id);
    $click_sql = "
    SELECT *
    FROM click_count
    WHERE user_id = ?
    AND page_url = ?
    ";
    $click_stmt = $con->prepare($click_sql);
    $click_stmt->execute(array($user_id, $curPage));
    $click_stmt_rows = $click_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $page_count = $click_stmt->rowCount();
    foreach ($click_stmt_rows as $click_stmt_row) {
        $setup_status = $click_stmt_row['setup'];
        $page_total_count = $click_stmt_row['page_count'];
    }
    if ($page_count == 0) {
        $click_insert_sql = "
            INSERT INTO click_count
            (user_id, page_url, page_count, setup)
            VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE page_count=page_count+1;
        ";
        $click_insert_stmt = $con->prepare($click_insert_sql);
        $click_insert_stmt->execute(array($user_id, $curPage, 1, $setup));
    }
    else {      
        $click_update_sql = "
            UPDATE click_count
            SET page_count=page_count+1
            WHERE user_id = ?
            AND page_url = ?
        ";
        $click_update_stmt = $con->prepare($click_update_sql);
        $click_update_stmt->execute(array($user_id, $curPage));
    }
```

Table

```
click_count
CREATE TABLE `click_count` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `page_url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `page_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `setup` int(5) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `page_url` (`page_url`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: If you always fall into update indicates that $page_count is not zero.. Try to echo() it to see maybe..  I would probably first try to add another user into click_count table and then it may become easier to see where it goes wrong..

Comment: Why are you bothering to decide between inserts and updates anyway? The way you're doing stuff right now, the insert would take care of either case (assuming your keys are set up right).

Comment: I've been staring at this for like 5 mins. and possibly other people. Are you relying on a logged in user and if so, where and how is this defined?

Comment: Yes. I am relying on a logged in user. I am carrying the user_id via a session. This value is correct as well. Both `var_dump($user_id)` and `var_dump($page_count)` dump the correct values.

Comment: so, is the session started in all pages using sessions and do they hold their value for the user in each page? this could also be a cache issue, and/or that the user wasn't logged out also.

Comment: Yes, the value is transferring to all pages. The dumped value is showing it correctly and I have cleared the cache.

Comment: what's the column type for the page count?

Comment: and that `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` I think you want to just do a regular `fetch()` to get the array of that row.

Comment: If the page_count equals to int 0, your if-statement should be running. Your variable is either not 0 or you did not show the entire code.

Comment: It also could be because of the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. As per the manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html *"For example, if column a is declared as **UNIQUE** and contains the value 1, the following two statements have similar effect"*. At this point, I'm baffled. There probably should be a unique key assigned to `page_count` also.

Comment: This is what displays with both var_dumps in place... `string(21) "I am the user id ==56" string(23) "I am the row count == 0"`

Comment: Then for the user who is in the `click_count` db ... `string(21) "I am the user id ==24" string(23) "I am the row count == 1"`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I added the unique jey to `page_count`... it didn't help though.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I figured it out. I used johnyTee's advise and tried adding another user to the database manually and it wouldn't let me because of the unique index for the `page_url` column. I then removed the unique index from it and now it works perfectly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: so in turn, `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` didn't work because there were no "duplicates" to update/insert, just the one record, as I suspected.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Is there a way to get it to work? someone tried introducing it to me when I was doing this and I couldn't get it to work, so I just added the normal `UPDATE` query.

Comment: you could do a regular update, such as `UPDATE table SET col_x = col_x + 1 WHERE col_y = ?` or `UPDATE table SET col_x = 0|1 WHERE col_y = ?` (boolean 0-1) type of thing (the latter probably what you want), if that's what you're asking. But didn't you already say it was working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is only the one user in the table, there is no record "to insert/update", therefore
[`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) failed you *silently*.

A regular [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) will suffice:

I.e. and as an example:

```
UPDATE table SET col_x = 0|1 WHERE col_y = ? // (boolean 0-1)
```

Note:

If ever you wish to increase a column by counting later on, the syntax would be:

```
UPDATE table SET col_x = col_x + 1 WHERE col_y = ?
```

---

In regards to your asking about how you could improve on your code:

> *@Fred-ii- Thanks. Yes, it is working now how I want, but if there are ways to improve the code I am always willing to try to learn it. I just remembered people in the past saying that I didn't need the update query at all with the duplicate key update. – Paul*

You could use named placeholders `:name` rather than `?` since they are easier to keep track of, but this is of course a matter of opinion that I feel is also shared by many and not just myself.

---

**Footnotes/credits:**

I would like to also give credit to the following comment:

> *"If you always fall into update indicates that $page_count is not zero.. Try to echo() it to see maybe.. I would probably first try to add another user into click_count table and then it may become easier to see where it goes wrong.. – johnyTee"*

where the OP responded with:

> *"@Fred-ii- I figured it out. I used johnyTee's advise and tried adding another user to the database manually and it wouldn't let me because of the unique index for the page_url column. I then removed the unique index from it and now it works perfectly. Thanks for the help! – Paul"*

Comment: Thanks again for all of the help!

Comment: @Paul You're most welcome Paul.

Answer (score 0):

It may be '0' (a string).  You can use intval to convert it to an integer.

```
$page_count = intval( $click_stmt->rowCount() );
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

Comment: The dumped value is appearing as such `int(0)`.

Comment: Maybe try the opposite. `if($page_count) { /* it's true or has value */ } else { /* it's false, zero or null */ }`

Answer (score 0):

from PHP PDO doc http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

> PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by a
>   DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement.

if you need th number of rows  in select you should use somethings like

```
$sql = "SELECT *
FROM click_count
WHERE user_id = ?
AND page_url = ?
"; 
$result = $con->prepare($sql); 
$result->execute(); 
$number_of_rows = $result->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: My `$page_count` variable was correct. The `fetchColumn()` gave me `bool(false)` for either the record being in or not.

Comment: @Paul   my is a suggestion .. hope is useful ..

Answer (score 0):

For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement. Instead, use PDO::query() to issue a SELECT COUNT(*) statement with the same predicates as your intended SELECT statement, then use PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve the number of rows that will be returned. Your application can then perform the correct action.

try like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*)
FROM click_count
WHERE user_id = ?
AND page_url = ?
"; 

if ($res = $conn->query($sql)) {

    /* Check the number of rows that match the SELECT statement */
    if ($res->fetchColumn() > 0) {
        //insert
    }else {
        //update
    }
}
```